# Contact Form 7 - get error messages in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to pass CF7 validation error messages my JavaScript. These ones...

[image]

When a form is sent and errors exists, how would I:

- prevent messages from displaying in default way?
- pass the appropriate error message value(s) to JavaScript so I can do my own thing with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily retrieve all error messages via php and pass it down to js the way you prefer :

```
WPCF7_ContactForm::get_instance( $YOUR_FORM_ID )->get_properties()['messages'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of usage, as indicated in answer above.

```
function ttoc_scripts_method()
  {
    if (is_front_page())
     wp_enqueue_script('ttoc-custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom_script.js', array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_localize_script(
    'ttoc-custom-script',
    'ttoc_cf7',
    array(
        'messages' => json_encode(WPCF7_ContactForm::get_instance(123)->get_properties()['messages']),
    )
);
}
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ttoc_scripts_method');
```

In JS(frontend) you can get the set messages like

```
let msg = JSON.parse(ttoc_cf7.messages).invalid_email;
```